# How to bypass firewall and NAT with reverse SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, firewall, nat, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to generate an SSH server in a machine behind a router.

First I tried to bind the SSH to my public IP address:

```
ssh -R 10002:localhost:22 <ip_address>
```

Then I'm prompted with a password request, however my username password doesn't seem to work.

Obviously I know my username password, so it seems to me that it's trying to authenticate in  another computer under the same network.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

It would also help me any alternative on how to create an SSH server behind a Router when you don't have access to the Router.

The ports in iptables are all open.

**UPDATE**

As suggested by [Thomas Oster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2858218/thomas-oster) answer I've tried the following.

In the machine behind the router I've executed the following command:

`$ ssh -R10002:localhost:22 <remote_public_ip_address> -l <my_remote_server_username>`

`<remote_ip_address>` being the remote_ip_address of a server with public IP and SSH server on which I have full control.

`<my_remote_server_username>` being the remote server username.

After that, I've tried to connect from the remote server to the server behind the router like this:

`$ ssh -p 10002 <remote_public_ip_address>`

However this command displays the following output:

```
ssh: connect to host <remote_public_ip_address> port 10002: Connection refused
```

So I opened the 10002 port in the iptables firewall using the following command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 10002 -j ACCEPT
```

After that I've executed again the command but it displays the same error message.

In my machine behind the router I have all ports open in iptables.

**UPDATE 2**

> You have to allow port-forwarding in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config of the
>   remove_public_ip_address server

I've tried to allow portforwarding in the sshd_config file adding this command:

```
LocalForward 10002 <my_remote_public_server_ip>:22
```

But it gave me this error message:

```
Bad configuration option: LocalForward
```

> After "ssh -R...." did you leave the window open?

After executing that command, it connects to the remote public machine, and yes, I left the window open.

> Can you use ssh -p 10002 localhost on the public server after the
>   tunnel is created?

Yes, if I execute that command in the public server, it connects after asking me for credentials.

> Please try "ssh localhost" on the machine behind the router to check if sshd is running and working.

This also works.

**UPDATE 3**

I've been finally able to make it work (thanks again to [Thomas Oster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2858218/thomas-oster))

We are going to work with three machines:

Destination Machine: That we want to connect to.

Middle Machine: A server acting as an intermediary for the connection (a Linode in my case)

Home Computer: Where we will access to the destination machine.

These are the steps I followed

**Step 1:**

```
[destination computer]$ vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Add the GatewayPorts option:

GatewayPorts   yes

Restart ssh.

**Step 2:**

```
[destination computer]$ ssh -R 4040:localhost:22 middle-machine-user@middle-machine-public-ip
```

This will link your public machine with your destination computer via port 4040

It will connect to the middle machine and prompt the terminal, you must leave this tab open.

**Step 3:**

Connect from home:

```
ssh destination-user@destination-ip -p4040
```

Or connect from the middle machine:

```
[home computer]$ ssh middle-machine-user@middle-machine-ip

[middle computer]$ ssh destination-user@localhost -p4040
```

[Source](http://linuxers.org/article/reverse-ssh-tunneling-bypassing-firewalls-and-nat)

Comment: You have to allow port-forwarding in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config of the remove_public_ip_address server

Comment: After "ssh -R...." did you leave the window open? The tunnel is only active as long as the connection is open. Did it shown any error messages like "could not bind to 10002"? Can you use ssh -p 10002 localhost on the public server after the tunnel is created?

Comment: Please try "ssh localhost" on the machine behind the router to check if sshd is running and working.

Comment: If what you wan't is HTTP or HTTPS, you can also try [burrow.io](https://burrow.io), the free account lets you open 1 HTTP reverse tunnel, and all you gotta do is run a curl command on the machine that is listening on port 4040. You setup the tunnel at the website. It's pretty cool.

Comment: I think in Step 3 you meant `ssh destination-user@middle-ip -p4040`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a ssh-server running on the public "ip_address"? What you're trying to do is "open ssh connection to "ip_address" and then tunnel any incoming request on port 10002 to localhost:22".

If "ip-address" is the public IP address of your dsl-router, you have to create a port-forwarding in the router's configuration to your host:22.

If you do not have access to the router, the only possible thing would be if you had access to another server running ssh in the internet, from which you can tunnel.

```
# open a session to the public available machine and create a tunnel from port 10002 back  to your local sshd (22)
ssh -R 10002:localhost:22 ip_of_public_server
# as long as this session is open, all calls to the public available machine on port 10002 will be tunneled to your local machine (make sure sshd is running on port 22)
ssh -p 10002 ip_of_public_server
```

Comment: I don't know which SSH server is running on the public ip address. But I do have another server running a SSH server with public IP and full control over it in another network. However I don't know exactly how to create a tunnel there that would be linked with this computer behind a Router. Meaning I can connect from my computer behind the router to the other SSH server, but I don't know how to do it the other way around.

Comment: OK. Let's assume your public computer has IP-Adrress public_ip. Then go to your machine behind the router and do "ssh -R10002:localhost:22 public_ip". If this works, you can connect from everywhere to the machine behind the router with "ssh -p 10002 public_ip"

Comment: please accept the answer if it's working for you, or describe where your problem is.

Comment: I've updated the post with the answer to your suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As you said we have "destination machine" (where we wanto to connect to using ssh), "middle machine" (public server working as forwarder), "other computers" (any other computer on the net)

As @thomas-oster said you have to use

```
[destination computer] $ ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 ip_of_public_server
```

However, in order for the tunnel to bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost, you have to use GatewayPorts in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the "middle machine" (public server):

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

Of course you have to restart sshd after adding this option.

Read http://www.snailbook.com/faq/gatewayports.auto.html for an explanation:
"by default SSH only listens for connections to the forwarded port on the loopback address"

This will allow you to connect from any computer on the net to your destination computer using the ip of the middle machine (public server):

```
[any computer on the net] $ ssh -p 2222 ip_of_public_server
```

Make sure your firewall on the public server allows connections to port 2222/tcp.

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled upon the same problem, but without having root privileges on the SSH server.

As mentioned `GatewayPorts yes` is needed so also clients from network are able to connect to remote forwarding port on the SSH server. By default it is set to `no`. Thus if you don't have root privileges you cannot change SSHD settings to set `GatewayPorts` option to `true`. But in that case you can use the following workaround:

```
ssh -R 4041:localhost:22 myserver.com 'socat TCP-LISTEN:4040,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:4041'
```

[socat](https://github.com/craSH/socat) is a great network utility which binds a TCP port `4040` on interface `0.0.0.0` so it is visible from network and redirects all traffic to the `127.0.0.1:4041` where SSHD is listening and redirecting it to your client's port `22`.

Thus if somebody wants to connect your local SSH on port 22 as you described (on the client) he does:

```
ssh -p 4040 myserver.com
```

and it works like this:

`SSH client --> myserver.com:4040 (socat) --> 127.0.0.1:4041 (myserver.com, SSHD) --> SSH client port 22`

[socat](https://github.com/craSH/socat) can be either built from sources or already installed on the system. It is present in the RPMForge repositories for RHEL/CentOS (however if you don't have root privileges you cannot install it).