# Nat vodafone mobile italia

Tags: mobile, nat

I'm trying to display some cameras connected to a dvr which in turn is connected to a Huawei router that has the ability to connect to the Internet via the mobile network.

I tried with a tim card and everything goes wonderfully (the tim's ip is dynamic so I have used no-ip to be able to always access the dvr and I made the forwarding by opening the right doors outside to the inside), but as the area in which you installed the dVR, it does not take tim signal (not even wind, or 3), I had to put the vodafone's sim but from what I've read on the internet but not the public ip to mobile customers, but access through NAT ..

None of you know the way to be able to access a remote PC via a network that uses NAT?

Comment: Please use English on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When behind NAT, the best course of action is to establish a connection from *inside* the NAT to some remote machine.

There are several ways to achieve that, such as [creating a (reverse) ssh tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269385/how-to-bypass-firewall-and-nat-with-reverse-ssh-tunnel) or using a remote desktop utility such as [logmein](https://secure.logmein.com/), [teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) or [ammyy](http://www.ammyy.com/en/).